# I am new to golang programming, I'm not sure why the results are not what I expected！

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func printSlice(slice []int) {
    slice[0] = 11
    log.Infof("sli %o", slice)
}

func main() {
    arr := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    log.Infof("Arr out %o", arr)
    slice := arr[3:]
    printSlice(slice)
    log.Infof("sli out %o", slice)
    log.Infof("Arr out2 %o", arr)
}
```

Why the result is:

```
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="Arr out [1 2 3 4 5 6]"
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="sli [13 5 6]"
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="sli out [13 5 6]"
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="Arr out2 [1 2 3 13 5 6]"
```

I think the result should be:

```
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="Arr out [1 2 3 4 5 6]" 
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="sli [11 5 6]"
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="sli out [11 5 6]"
time="2024-03-12T11:38:44+09:00" level=info msg="Arr out2 [1 2 3 11 5 6]"
```

My golang version is 1.18.10

Comment: Hi there, welcome, please provide more details on your post, otherwise it's likely that you can't find your answer

Comment: Your title should describe the specific question well enough that someone can know if they have the same problem (and are likely to be helped by your question's answers) from a search result list without clicking through. "Why doesn't modifying an element of a slice in-place change the corresponding element of the array it was made from?" would be a much clearer title, if that's what you mean to ask.

Comment: (Whereas if the question is *Why does `fmt.Printf("%o", 11)` write `13` on output?*, you could have asked that question on its own without conflating it with a bunch of logic around slices and in-place mutation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the docs for [fmt](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt):

> %o base 8

So you are printing your output in [base 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), if you change this to base 10 (`%d`) you will get the expected results ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TpPG5bJ1USR)).

```
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Arr out [1 2 3 4 5 6]"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="sli [11 5 6]"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="sli out [11 5 6]"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Arr out2 [1 2 3 11 5 6]"
```

> My golang version is 1.18.10

Note that version 1.18 was released in 2022, I'd suggest moving to a supported release (e.g. 1.22 which was released in February), as per the [release policy](https://go.dev/doc/devel/release#policy):

> Each major Go release is supported until there are two newer major releases. For example, Go 1.5 was supported until the Go 1.7 release, and Go 1.6 was supported until the Go 1.8 release. We fix critical problems, including critical security problems, in supported releases as needed by issuing minor revisions (for example, Go 1.6.1, Go 1.6.2, and so on).

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought o% was printing an object.

Comment: @BarryZhu "I thought o% was printing an object." Fundamental things must not be guessed but looked up in the reference manual, here the package doc. Unlike as in several other languages it is highly recommended that you read the documentation of _each_ package and _each_ function/method/type you use.